# Excel join two table by field list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

Hello can you help i need join two tables in Excel by power query

First:

1. ID
2. Name

Second:

1. Field
2. Field2
3. List of ids

I make this operation but got error

```
 Table.NestedJoin(#"Table2",{"List of ids"},#"Table1",{"ID"},"NewField",JoinKind.LeftOuter)
```

[image]

Update:

[image]

Update:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

In Table1, adds column containing tables of matching rows from Table2, where the ID from Table2 matches one of the items from Group3ID list on Table1

**Table1**

```
let Source = #table({"ID", "Group3ID","Group1"},{{1,{80,2,100,110},"a"},{2,{70,90,4,110},"b"},{3,{60,90,3,110},"c"},{4,{60,90,3,5},"d"},{5,{50,90,100,110},"e"},{6,{30,4,1,110},"f"}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Expanded Group3ID" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Index", "Group3ID"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.SelectColumns(Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Group3ID", {"Group3ID"}, Table2, {"ID"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),{"Index", "Table2"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.SelectColumns(Table.Group(#"Merged Queries", {"Index"}, {{"MatchedRows", each Table.Combine(_[Table2])}}),{"MatchedRows"}),
Combined = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source) & Table.ToColumns(#"Grouped Rows"),Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"Match"})
in Combined
```

**Table2**

```
let Source = #table({"ID", "Group3ID","Group1"},{{1,{80,2,100,110},"a"},{2,{70,90,4,110},"b"},{3,{60,90,3,110},"c"},{4,{60,90,3,5},"d"},{5,{50,90,100,110},"e"},{6,{30,4,1,110},"f"}})
in Source
```

Comment: And what different from my code? As you can see you got 1 value in lst of ids, but i got List of value, i attach the screenshot

Comment: Add new picture

Comment: Why is table1 identical to tablE2?  You want to merge tabel2 unto table1 under what criterion

Comment: Its just example Table1,Table2 with the same structure but need join Group3Id from first table on Id from Second table, where Group3Id is a List field with many values of id in cell

Comment: Expand Group3ID list first, then merge it

Comment: Yes, but how then it make in one row?

Comment: provided new code

Comment: its seems good, but on load full data i got error attach screen

Comment: I dont know what your source data looks like  It works fine for the sample data provided